# How do you prove the following formula concerning the complex modulus and it's logarithm, complex argument and natural logarithm??

Tags: complex-analysis

Introduction the the problem:
*w*=e^*z* which implies ln(w)=z. Where both *z* and *w* are complex numbers. Then the formula states that: *z*= log(*r*) + *ix*.
Where *r* is the complex modulus and *x* is the complex argument.

This isn't a homework assingment, its just our of curiosity, thanks!

Comment: That is just how you define the complex logarithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: If we write $\theta$ for the argument, then $z = r e^{i\theta}$ is "polar coordinates".  And this logarithm fact is essentially a restatement of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w$ be a complex number. We can write it as $w=r\cdot e^{ix}$ where $r$ is the modulus and $x$ is the argument. Taking the log of both sides gives:

$$\ln w = \ln r\cdot e^{ix}$$
$$\ln w = \ln r + \ln e^{ix}$$
$$\ln w = \ln r + ix\cdot \ln e$$
$$\ln w = \ln r + ix$$

Comment: This is misleading at best. Are you for example claiming that $\ln 1 = \ln e^{2\pi i} = 2\pi i$ and $\ln 1 =\ln e^0 = 0$ so that $2\pi i = 0$?

Comment: Also the usual rules are not valid without restriction for complex logarithms. (In general $\log zw \neq \log z + \log w$.)

Comment: If $z = re^{iθ}$ with $r > 0$ (polar form), then $w = \ln r + iθ$ is one logarithm of $z$; adding integer multiples of $2πi$ gives all the others.

Comment: Yes, but that's not even close to what you wrote in your answer.

Comment: I just left of the $2\pi i$ for simplicity of explaining the formula.

Comment: But the formula has (on the right) logr and not lnr.

Comment: It must be an implied $\log_e$. (Or a typo.)